# duplicated rows which have duplicated primary key in a view

Tags: hibernate

i have i view (2 tables ans 1 association) and i mappe it like this

```
@Id
@Column(name = "IDBQ", precision = 5, scale = 0)
public Integer getIdbq() {
    return this.idbq;
}

public void setIdbq(Integer idbq) {
    this.idbq = idbq;
}


@Column(name = "IDR", precision = 22, scale = 0)
public Integer getIdr() {
    return this.idr;
}

public void setIdr(Integer idr) {
    this.idr = idr;
}

@Column(name = "NOM_CLIENT",  length = 100)
public String getNomClient() {
    return this.nomClient;
}

public void setNomClient(String nomClient) {
    this.nomClient = nomClient;
}

@Column(name = "PRENOM_CLIENT",  length = 30)
public String getPrenomClient() {
    return this.prenomClient;
}
```

and beacause it's a view the primary key **IDBQ** in many rows is duplicated.
the probleme when i make a request hql from hibernate it return : duplicated rows which have duplicated Id -> IDBQ

if i have :

```
IDBQ -- IDR -- NOM_CLIENT -- PRENOM_CLIENT
1       1     xx            xxx
1       2     yy            yyy
```

it return me in my hql request

```
1       1     xx            xxx
1       1     xx            xxx
```

but the sql request work fin !

Answer (score 1):

If you have several rows with the same ID in your view, then it means that your ID is not an ID. From what you posted it seems like `[IDBQ, IDR]` should be the ID of the entity.

Comment: no but this is just a view with 2 tables and a association so the primary key in table 1 (IDBQ) will be repeated in the association.
i don't wanna that `[IDR]` (primary key of table 2) be apart of the primary key.

Comment: You don't have the choice. A primary key, by definition, is unique among all the records.

Comment: but when i make sql request i have no problem, why the duplicated rows are just with hibernate ?

Comment: Hibernate needs an ID that uniquely identifies a row in the view. You've told it to use a column that is not unique. It can't work.

Comment: Hibernate needs a **unique** key, SQL do not need that. Find the unique key in your view. Here it is probably idbq + idr. If the view does not have a unique key, it can't be mapped in Hibernate; in that case you have to change the view (or use createSqlQuery for native SQL).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see duplicate rows is because you have 2 records with same primary key (IDBQ in your case). While retrieving data from database, records with same identifier would reference the same object (depending on the order). This is called Identity Map Patter. [Follow this link for more info !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_map_pattern)

Even though your view has 2 different rows with same identifier on your query editor, Your Entity Framework produces incorrect output. 
When the 1st row with IDBQ value '1' is loaded from the database it is retrieved as expected but when the 2nd row with same IDBQ value '1' is retrieved, the same object is returned (1  | 1 | xx | xxx) since there is an object with PK '1' already loaded.
Hope you find this helpful.